# Assign keyboard shortcuts to drag and drop elements in a webpage

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility, keyboard-events

I have drag and drop feature in one of the pages of my web application. The events have been handled using jquery. I would like to replicate the drag and drop operation of the mouse using the keyboard only. I believe this would make my app more accessible. Is there a way to it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to provide a completely different view, as even with ARIA you still cannot replicate the need to physically move a control.

One example is to list all the objects the user can move, and within each object provide a set of options for where the user wants to move it.

For example, here is an item to be moved (duplicate and change the letter as needed):

```
<div id="itemA">
  <p>
    <strong>Item A</strong>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="selA">Move to:</label><br>
    <select id="selA">
      <option value="c1">Column 1</option>
      <option value="c2">Column 2</option>
      <option value="c3">Column 3</option>
    </select><br>
    <button onclick="MoveItem('itemA',selA.value);">Move</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Here are the containers to which it can be moved (I used a `table` simply because I am pretending you are using a grid, but your containers can be whatever is structurally/semantically appropriate):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="c1"></td>
    <td id="c2"></td>
    <td id="c3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I do not use jQuery, but I am sure you can abstract this plain JavaScript function into your preferred syntax:

```
function MoveItem(itemID, colID) {
  try {
    var Item = document.getElementById(itemID);
    var Col = document.getElementById(colID);
    Col.appendChild(Item);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('MoveItem(): ' + e);
  }
}
```

That's it. No ARIA, no libraries, no need to worry about mobility.

I also have that entire example as a CodePen so you can give it a go and see how it works: http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/OXkaLW

Answer (score 1):

> ### [Accessible Drag and Drop Using WAI-ARIA](https://dev.opera.com/articles/accessible-drag-and-drop/)
>
> This article is intended for people who create rich internet
>   applications with drag and drop functionality and want to make them
>   accessible. No prior knowledge of WAI-ARIA is assumed, although it is
>   recommended you read my introduction to WAI-ARIA article before
>   starting this article. A basic knowledge of scripting is assumed, and
>   is necessary to understand exactly what is going on in the code
>   example, but this knowledge is not necessary to understand the basic
>   concepts discussed.

**Drag and drop using WAI-ARIA**

WAI-ARIA provides two properties to help make drag and drop accessible to users of assistive technologies:

- `aria-grabbed`
- `aria-dropeffect`

[Accessible Drag and Drop Example](https://dev.opera.com/articles/accessible-drag-and-drop/example.html)

Comment: drag and drop properties are deprecated in aria 1.1.  see 

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#dragdrop